# Alarm issue Android Application

Tags: java, android, xml, alarm

having some issues with my alarm, when it works it shows me my project name in the middle

**mypropject name is: LMP**

[image: mypropject name is: LMP]

and I couldn't do anything until i press back button

How can I get ride from this problem can anyone suggest me !

Answer (score 0):

Seems like u use an AlertDialog (or sth) and don't have the buttons u want.
Try "setPositiveButton()" and "setNegativeButton()" to have a Ok/Cancel.

Furthermore.. more details are appreciated! ;)

(Otherwise, if u use an AlertManager (a real alert ^^) then u could cancel the repeating Dialog by using the same intent to the alertManager in myAlertManager.cancel(intent) ... or sth... )

Comment: thanks for answering me but i didn't get ur solution, can I update my question and show my code ? thanks in advance

Comment: @Samiah Not only you *can*. You really **should**.